# Remove file inside a folder from Git history

Tags: git

I want to remove the file test.php from my git history which is inside the folder example. Like /example/test.php.

after removing I want it to like /example

but when I using this,

```
git filter-branch — index-filter “git rm -rf — cached — ignore-unmatch example/test.php” HEAD
```

it removes the whole example folder. Help me in solving this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any other files in the folder? If not, it's most likely because GIT ignores empty folders.

Comment: Yes in my example folder with multiple files and folder with single file is there.but in both cases i need to remove the file alone not the folder. give me a best solution

Comment: Since you can't have empty folders in GIT, you can simply create a file called `.gitkeep` in that folder and it will exist in your repository. If you're dynamically generating files (like logs/uploads or similar) that you want to ignore but still always want to commit the folder, you can create a `.gitignore`-file in the folder. In that file, add `*` on the first row and `!.gitignore` on the second row. That says that it should ignore all files, except itself. If that's not what you're after, you need to update your question with more specifics.

Comment: try dropping the `-r` in `-rf`  -- it's just a blind suggestion, but since you want to only remove on single file and not a complete directory, the `-r` should not have an impact on the resulting action.